# Log-Linear Ratios

Tags: logarithms, word-problem, ratio

I'm working on the problem below, and I would be extremely thankful if anyone could provide pointers or corrections to what I've done so far.

Here is the question:

> Using a base $10$ log-linear plot, if $x = 10$ and $x = 1000$ are $1$ cm apart, what is the distance between $x = 1000$ and $x = 1500$? (In other words, where—when drawn on a log base $10$ scale—do $x = 10, 1000,$ and $ 1500 $ correspond to the analogous linear number line?)

I was thinking of making a ratio between the two and solving for $x$, such as $\frac{0.01}1=\frac{0.66}x)$, but I don't think I've done it correctly. Again, any help would be much appreciated! Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: I have submitted an edit for $\LaTeX$. In the future, please include $\LaTeX$ and [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The distance should be **linearly** proportional to the difference in the base-10 logarithms of the two values of $x$.

You are given that as the base-10 logarithm goes from $(1)$ to $(3)$ that the distance is $(1)$ cm.

So, given that $\log_{10}(1500) \approx 3.176$, you have that the distance between $(1500)$ and $(1000),$ measured in cm, should approximately be

$$\frac{1}{3 - 1} \times \left[3.176 - 3.000\right] = \frac{0.176}{2}.$$